# Is there a way to control leftViewMode (UITextFieldViewMode) and leftView from within Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, interface-builder

I would like to set a `leftView` and `leftViewMode` of my `UITextField` directly in Interface Builder.

I assume this is not possible, since I couldn't find it anywhere in the *Attributes Inspector*. Just to make sure before I start implementing this in code, did I oversee the way how to do it or is it really not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, by setting the `User Defined Runtime Attributes` in the Utilities pane.

[image]

Here `leftViewMode` property is set. The value here is `UITextFieldViewModeAlways`. You can set relevant value by looking at the declaration of `UITextFieldViewMode` ENUM:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITextFieldViewMode) {
    UITextFieldViewModeNever,
    UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing,
    UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing,
    UITextFieldViewModeAlways
};
```

As you can see, it is `NSInteger`, and values begin with 0, so relevant values for modes:

**0** (`UITextFieldViewModeNever`),

**1** (`UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing`),

**2** (`UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing`) and

**3** (`UITextFieldViewModeAlways`)